# Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently of Android Training

Tags: android, bitmap

In the official Training of Android Web,in the episode "Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently#Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI",the first implementation of `ImageDetailFragment`, there is a drawback of it which is the images are being read from resources on the UI thread.And in its improvement, in the method `loadBitmap`, it has already called `mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder)` on the UI thread before start a`BitmapWorkerTask` in which it calls `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`So, whats the difference between `mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder)` and `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`,don't they both read from the resource?

Comment: No. A `Bitmap` is a fully loaded image. Internally `setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder)` also just loads a `Bitmap` from a resource and then sets it to the `ImageView`.

Comment: You mean `setImageResource(R.drawable.image_placeholder)` loads a `bitmap` object which has already been created, not just starts reading from the resource which will lead application hanging,right?So why don't change `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` to `imageView.setImageResource(resId)`?